# How to fix 401 Unauthorized with Twitter oAuth

Tags: twitter, oauth

Hopefully someone here can help me fix this. I have been trying to make a web app for twitter, I have setup my application in the developer section of the twitter website.

I have set a callback url in both the developer section and in my code.

Where I get stuck is I get a 401 Unauthorized exception when requesting the Access Token. The app correctly sends the user to Twitter to ask for authorization, and then twitter send back to my callback URL successfully. My webapp then tries to request the access token and thats when the exceptions happens.

Below is an example of the API I call:
    https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token?oauth_callback=http://www.example.com&oauth_consumer_key=6Rfhub7fDgCIazdg4dMECT6fJ&oauth_nonce=1721260&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1403965501&oauth_token=RCbfmuvzqFjJWHwCtWfNqEQ22uXFvv422AtHfBBYE&oauth_verifier=0QuTFy5SBmAl29VIWkBjfogJQ7GiSAoR2qIjokoii0&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=JRzlH5Fiv5Ani3P+oXj5dxV58cA=

Any ideas where I might be going wrong?

Thanks

EDIT: Im using code from here http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/05/add-twitter-login-authentication-to.html

and I changed it to use https:// not http://

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't fix this issue. Using TweetSharp instead.